# How to resolve is down for maintenance with Force.com sites

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, site.com

I created a Force.com site and linked a Visualforce page with it, but when I access the link I get down for maintenance error page. I am not sure how to get my visual force page instead of this error. I made the force.com website as active too but I still this error page. I saw this help link - [https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000099UQIAY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4IWj.jpg)

But I do not know what it means by putting my visualforce in a folder.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience down for maintenance usually means you have an incorrect URL. make sure that you have found the correct link to the Site.

Example:

http://yourdomain.force.com/SiteName/apex/VisualforcePageName

The link you reference says that the person created a new site sub-domain. Created a new "SiteName" and it seemed to have resolved his error (my guess is that something else was going on).

[image]

Comment: How do I know I am using the right URL? I have a VF page- CreateContact and I have the domain created as http://dev-nycbusiness.cs41.force.com/ . I tried to make the URL as http://dev-nycbusiness.cs41.force.com/CreateContact but it did not work.

Comment: Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: What is the name of the subdomain for your site? Give me the value of what is underneath the column of "Site URL" when on the Sites setting page

Comment: Also can you verify that the "Active" checkbox is checked on the Site Details for this particular subdomain?

Comment: Please see the edit, I have pasted the screen shot of my domain setting.

Comment: Change inactive site home page to your visualforce page

Comment: I did that but I still get the same error- down for maintenance.

Comment: Did you add your "CreateContact" visualforce page as a valid page in the Site Settings? Check my answer for screen shot

Comment: I added the createcontact in site visualforce page section. I enable the visualforce page to have public access. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah that is what I meant - try have the subdomain differ from the visualforce page as the home page. This could be causing some kind of conflict.

Comment: I changed the URL to - http://dev-nycbusiness.cs41.force.com/Contact , but I still get the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31157/discussion-between-rdvsm-and-chris).

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem when using Salesforce's REST API. It seems that "We are down for maintenance" simply means that something unspecified was wrong with your request. The error is a red herring.

In our case, the body of the request was malformed. The body wasn't needed; we removed it and the request succeeded.